# Make emacs file variable header take effect

Tags: emacs, configuration

I frequently paste the line

```
# -*- org-export-with-sub-superscripts: {}; -*-
```

into my .org files. To get this to take effect for the next export, the simplest way I've found is to kill the buffer and reopen the file. How can I make this happen without killing the buffer (which is clumsy and loses *undo* history)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `M-x normal-mode` to have the file-local variables reapplied.